# Use WhatsApp anonymously

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I want someone to be able contact me on WhatsApp. I would prefer to give him an anonymous account.

Is there such thing?

I don't want him to know my phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible. Even if you send him a message without him adding you as a contact the first thing he will see is your number.

Comment: any other app or way then? To IM anonymously?